# dynamic gui's in Kivy

Tags: kivy

I am considering diving into Kivy, but i have one question that is very important for my application:

is it possible to generate Kivy guis on the flight. I have seen the kv gui definition language, but in my use case a kivy app would download a gui (e.g. form) definition from a server and generate the gui/form on the flight (on the server the gui definition is also dynamically generated).

What would be the approach to implement this? For example is it possible to access and change the widget/layout tree that is normally generated from the kv definition?

Cheers, Lars

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is it possible to generate Kivy guis on the flight

Yes, it is, and it's a very normal thing to do.

kv just lets you define a state of the widget tree, it doesn't set anything in stone. You can use add_widget or remove_widget at any time to change what widgets are displayed.